# Не добавить null в базу данных при помощи .net tableadapter.insert null

Tags: vb.net, .net, null, oledb, база-данных

Вопрос по MS VS и .Net. Нужно мне написать WinForms приложение с базой данных. Конструктор создал схему БД xsd. Значения переменных типизированные. В автоматически созданном Tableadapter.Insert есть параметры с типами данных, например system.int32 в которые нужно вставить NULL (DBNull.Value) или Nothing. В базе данных эти поля могут быть Null.

Как вставить Null не прибегая к прямым SQL-командам? Хочется использовать insert с типизированными параметрами. Извините, если чего напутал, в программировании чайник )

Читал форумы, там пишут, что это давний глюк xsd.exe, который не умеет проставлять nullable типы данных параметрам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась преобразованием типов для всех параметров запроса

```
IIf(IsNothing(var1),Nothing,CInt(var1))
IIf(IsNothing(var2),Nothing,CSng(var2))
```

Для времени из Excel использовал DateTime.FromOADate(var3), еще помогло ускорить программу [объединение](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17680/Using-TableAdapters-with-transactions) tableadapter.insert в transaction. То есть похоже описанной проблемы не было, а отсутствовало правильное преобразование.